# What resources are available for using Qt as a toolkit for games

Tags: c++, qt

Qt is an excellent application toolkit and overall the best for C++. While some large projects use Qt (KDE for example), I haven't seen many games using it. So I decided to make my own. But what does Qt provide that may be useful when writing a game (in my case a 2D game)?

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely take a look at the [Qt Graphics View Framework](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/graphicsview.html), it does provide a nice hardware accelerated 2D scene graph (QtGraphicsScene).

Comment: The scene is optimized for static content, once you get to moving items around you'll hit cliffs where suddenly adding one more item to the moving ones will slow way down.  Just something to watch out for.

Answer (score 2):

There are games made with Qt, KDE has a lot of them, see http://games.kde.org/

Most of them are made using the graphics view framework, and the svg renderer.

Comment: RIGHT! I forgot about KDE games!